# Shell Script :: How to put multiple filter in grep command

Tags: python, json, linux, bash, shell

My current script is returning "userAccessId" value for all the blocks under "useraccesses". Below i have written the script and backend json response. I have filtered and getting "userAccessId" value for all the blocks under "useraccesses".

But my actual requirement is, i want to get "userAccessId" value whose "numberOfAccessSchedules" value are greater than zero.
Can someone please modify my script.

### MyScript.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#

export TOKEN=$(curl -k -s -d "client_id=guard-public" -d "grant_type=password" -d "username=test" -d "password=test@123" "https://10.00.00.00/auth/realms/guard/protocol/openid-connect/token" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['access_token']")
    
#GET UserAccess ID

#echo "GET useraccess ID for all users"

curl -k --location --request GET "https://10.00.00.00:111/guardian-restservice/v1/useraccesses?page=$i&page_size=10000" -k -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" | jq | grep "userAccessId" | awk -F : {'print $2'} | sed 's/,//' >> alluseraccessId.txt
```

## Backend JSON Response without filter

```
{
  "page": {
    "currentPage": 1,
    "totalPages": 7,
    "pageSize": 10000
  },
  "useraccesses": [
    {
      "userAccessId": 918568786,
      "numberOfAccessSchedules": 2,
      "customAttributes": {},
      "networkElementUserId": ""
    },
    {
      "userAccessId": 918569013,
      "numberOfAccessSchedules": 1,
      "customAttributes": {},
      "networkElementUserId": ""
    },
    {
      "userAccessId": 918569301,
      "numberOfAccessSchedules": 0,
      "customAttributes": {},
      "networkElementUserId": ""
    },
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
   ]
}
```

### Current O/P (alluseraccessId.txt)

```
918568786
918569013
918569301
```

### Expected O/P (alluseraccessId.txt)

```
918568786
918569013
```

Comment: Use `jq`, not `grep`, to work with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily extract the values you need with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), the de facto standard utility for working with JSON in shell scripts. Trying to apply regular expression based tools to structured data formats like JSON  or XML is almost always a bad idea.

```bash
curl ... | jq '.useraccesses[] | select(.numberOfAccessSchedules>0) | .userAccessId' >> alluseraccessId.txt
```

Adds

```
918568786
918569013
```

to the file.

Means 'for each element of the array in the `useraccesses` element of the top level object, if its `numberOfAccessSchedules` element is greater than 0, print the value of its `userAccessId` element.'

Comment: Thanks Shawn.. it is working and getting expected O/P.